# Web activity runs successfully although response contains Failed

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have  a web activity in my ADF which calls a Azure Function Httptrigger. The out put which web activity redieves is "Failed", but web activity show me everythings fine:

[image]

in such a situation, How can I force web activity to go to Failed status? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. One way to force web activity to fail is to give an invalid URL.
2. If you want to fail the pipeline based on web activity output value, you can pass the output value of web activity to If condition activity and add an activity to fail when false.

**Example**: I added an invalid URL inside False in **If Condition** activity to fail the pipeline forcefully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Idea. The second option is nice, but if in Azure Data Factory we do "rerun from failure" then ADF starts from if Condition and not the web activity. Do you have any idea how can I force ADF to start from "web activity" and not from "if Condition"?

Comment: "Rerun from failure activity" reruns pipeline from failed activity. There are other options "Rerun" which re-runs the complete pipeline and also "rerun from activity" where you can select from which activity the rerun should happen.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in my scenario, I have to use "Rerun from failure activity". Do you have any idea how can I force "Web activity" to fail when the runtimeStatus is "Failed"? Is it possible in your opinion? Should I do something on Azure function side?